# Не работает jquery.validate.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, валидация

Два проекта: основной и тестовый. В тестовом обычно только временные файлы, где производятся, к примеру, тесты готового кода.

В тестовом подключаю **jquery.validate.min.js** и сам **JQmin** - все великолепно работает.

Проделываю тоже самое в точности в основном проекте - не работает.
Есть подозрение, что кол-во возможных подключаемых файлов превышен (если такое возможно).

**head:**

```
<title>ДС "Зоренька"</title>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<meta name = "keywords" content = "" />
<meta name = "description" content = "" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href = "img/logo.ico" rel = "shortcut icon" type = "image/x-icon" />
<link href = "css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet" />
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nav.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validateformcontacts.js"></script>
```

Нужно сделать проверки на инпуты в форме, но мистика не дает.

Comment: А ссылку на страницу с формой можно??

Comment: ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Могу только листинг скинуть, проект автономный.  Ошибка одна: Uncaught SyntaxError: validateformcontacts.is:5 Unexpected token ;